# Mount an SD card over USB?

Tags: linux, usb, storage

I'm currently using:

> insmod g_file_storage.ko file=/dev/mmcblk0p1 stall=0 removable=1

This works as I can see the device in Windows. However when it comes to changing a file, the changes are not reflected on the Linux device. If I were to add a new file, this change is reflected. Same thing goes for renaming and removing.

I've been reading around that g_file_storage mounts a block rather than a filesystem. Is there any way to either:

1) Update the block when a file is changed so the Linux device sees the change
2) Use some other method to mount a filesystem over USB (can't use g_ether/g_serial)

This is for a GP2X Caanoo device.